# get table's schema name inside T4 template - EF6 - C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6, poco, t4

I'm working on a project using Entity Framework 6 + Postgre.

My database has many schemas.

I need to get the table's schema name inside my t4 file.

In EF4, i think it`s can be done with something like this:

http://jnye.co/Posts/3/getting-schema-information-from-an-edmx-file-with-poco

The table's schema name is in the metadata of the EDM file, in section:

```
    ...</EntityType>
    <EntityContainer Name="WWBLFATStoreContainer">
      <EntitySet Name="nota_fiscal" EntityType="Self.nota_fiscal" Schema="fat__t" store:Type="Tables" />
    </EntityContainer>
```

in above example, i want put "fat__t" in a variable, to use in the t4 template.

By what I read on internet, I need a reference to "metadataWorkspace", but I dont know how to refer to that inside the T4 Template...

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, does `Schema="fat__t"` not work?

Comment: I need to put "fat__t" in a variable, to use in my t4 template..

Comment: If you have the edmx file you need to create StoreItemCollection using this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646490(v=vs.110).aspx and passing the ssdl part. If you have context you can extract things from context. Some examples here: https://github.com/moozzyk/EF6CodeFirstViewGenT4TemplateCSharp/blob/master/PayloadUnzipped/EF6CodeFirstCSharp.Views.tt